# R Sankey Highchart: customizing node tooltip using data from a different variable

Tags: r, tooltip, sankey-diagram, r-highcharter

I'm trying to make a Sankey diagram with `highcharter` and I need to show in the node tooltip the sum of a variable, say `y`.  For instance, for node "A" the sum of `y` would be 62 (34+28).

I have tried this but it won't work

```
test <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "A", "B"), 
                   b = c("C", "C", "D", "D"), 
                   x = c(4, 9, 2, 2), 
                   y = c(34, 29, 28, 26)) 

hchart(test, "sankey", nodeWidth = 10, hcaes(from = a, to = b, weight = x)) %>% 
 hc_tooltip(nodeFormat = "{y.sum}")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below calculates the sum of y and shows it in the tooltip.

```
library(highcharter)    
test <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "A", "B"), 
                   b = c("C", "C", "D", "D"), 
                   x = c(4, 9, 2, 2), 
                   y = c(34, 29, 28, 26))   

hchart(test, "sankey", nodeWidth = 10, hcaes(from = a, to = b, weight = x)) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(nodeFormatter = JS("
    function() {
      // Function for y sum calculation
      function getSum(arr, val) {
        var idx = [], i, sumy=0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i].from==val | arr[i].to==val) {
            sumy = sumy + arr[i].y
          }
        }
        return(sumy)
      }
      // Get y sum and show it in the tooltip       
      sumy = getSum(this.series.options.data, this.name);
      var result = 'Node: ' + this.name + 
                   '<br>Sum y: <b>' + sumy + '</b>';
      return result;
    }")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormatter = JS("
    function() {
      // Function for y sum calculation
      function getSum(arr, val) {
        var idx = [], i, sumy=0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i].a==val) {
            sumy = sumy + arr[i].y
          }
        }
        return(sumy)
      }
      // Get y sum and show it in the tooltip       
      sumy = getSum(this.series.options.data, this.from);
      var result = this.from + ' -> ' + this.to + 
                   '<br>Sum y: <b>' + sumy + '</b>';
      return result;
    }")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your answer. Sorry I wasnt clear, I meant the sum of y for each node in the node tooltip, not the total sum of that variable. Fore instance, for "A" it would be 62 (34+28). Do you thin that is possible?

Comment: Hi @MarcoSandri. I think we are almost there. The tooltip I need to show that sum is the node tooltip (now it says, "undefined -> undefined Sum y:0"), the one you'll see when you put the mouse over the nodes (the A,B,C or D letters in this case). I tried to add the function you wrote to the nodeFormat but it didn't work, neither some variations I tried. Thanks